# Proper way to load structs in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I have been experimenting with MCJIT in LLVM and have come across a problem when trying to load struct types.

The relevant struct I am trying to load can be seen here:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} cfloat;
```

The generated LLVM code can be seen below.

```
--LLVM IR--
; ModuleID = 'Test_Module'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"

%cfloat = type { float, float }

declare float @cabs(%cfloat)

declare float @cabsptr(%cfloat*)

define i32 @test(i32 %argc, i8** %args) {
entry:
  %argloc0 = getelementptr i8*, i8** %args, i64 0
  %argloc1 = getelementptr i8*, i8** %args, i64 1
  %arg0 = load i8*, i8** %argloc0
  %iptr = bitcast i8* %arg0 to %cfloat*
  %arg1 = load i8*, i8** %argloc1
  %optr = bitcast i8* %arg1 to float*
  %ival = load %cfloat, %cfloat* %iptr
  %oval = call float @cabs(%cfloat %ival)
  %oval2 = call float @cabsptr(%cfloat* %iptr)
  store float %oval, float* %optr
  ret i32 %argc
}
```

The relevant structs and functions:

```
extern "C" float cabs(cfloat val)
{
    printf("%f, %f\n", val.x, val.y);
    return sqrtf(val.x * val.x + val.y * val.y);
}

extern "C" float cabsptr(cfloat *val)
{
    printf("%f, %f\n", val->x, val->y);
    return sqrtf(val->x * val->x + val->y * val->y);
}
```

When I pass in `cfloat val = {300, -400};` to the function

- `cabs` prints `300.0000, 0.0000`.
- `cabsptr` prints `300.0000, -400.0000`.

I'd expect both the functions to print the input values.

Is this a bug I am encountering or did I miss something when generating the LLVM function?

The full source code to reproduce this issue can be seen here:
https://gist.github.com/pavanky/4439f1a6c2ca182058c19187aa8215a7

---

**EDIT:**
Defining my custom type to be a `VectorType` of `<2 x float>` seems to be a work around for me. But I'd like to know a proper solution if available.

Comment: Did you try packing the structure?

Comment: @FrankC. It shouldn't matter in this case because both the fields are floats. But yes, I did try packing the struct as well.